# How to prevent CodeIgniter sessions from being destroyed when the browser is closed?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

CodeIgniter's session handler works great. However, the sessions it stores only last until the browser is closed. (*Also, is this correct behaviour?*)

I understand that PHP sessions only last until the browser is closed. However, I was under the impression that CodeIgniter's session system worked around this limitation based on whatever `$config['sess_expiration']` is set to. In my case, it is set to `60 * 60 * 24 * 365`.

I am hesitant to create my own system for tracking sessions with cookies because I feel like I'm missing something. Is there not a native way to securely store userdata in a cookie with CodeIgniter, and if there is, is that not through the CodeIgniter session library? How do I keep my sessions persistant for the duration of the time prior to the specified expiration?

how do I prevent CodeIgniter session user data from being destroyed when the browser is closed?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: $config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;

Comment: That did it. Not sure why that configuration option wasn't in my config.php file. Post your solution as an answer and I'll select it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Set in `$config` like this

```
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
```

To know more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It worked. however, I'm confused as to why the documentation calls that a legacy setting if it was indeed the solution.

Comment: the current documentation doesn't have any info about this ,the previous one has.may be in future it may obsolete in ci 4 with something more interesting